# Creating normal distributions with model uncertainty in Logistic Regression

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, standard-error

I have a GLM model, with a count predictor (length) and binary outcome.

```
response = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
input = c(5, 10, 2, 17, 19, 13, 3)
model = glm(response ~ input, family = "binomial")
summary(model)
```

The `summary(model)` gives me the standard error of the model - which is pretty high in this toy sample, but <1 in my actual data.

Next, I use predict, to see the probability of the response at 2 individual values of the input. So I say

```
prob1 = predict(model, newdata = data.frame(input = 15), type="response")
prob2 = predict(model, newdata = data.frame(input = 3), type="response")
```

I want to check if the difference between prob1 and prob2 is statistically significant or not. It is somewhat like comparing levels in a categorical variable, but my predictor is not categorical. So I generate normal distributions with the predicted probability in each case, with model error as the standard deviation.

```
distr_p1 = rnorm(100, prob1, model_SE)
distr_p2 = rnorm(100, prob2, model_SE)
```

Now I can do a `t.test(prob1, prob2)` and report the p-value. Would this be the right approach? Thank you so much!

Comment: This does not make too much sense. What are you trying to achieve? When predicting the probability for two different observations based on a model you have estimated, the only source of variance is the coefficient. You can create a test based on the variance of the estimated coefficients, is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello - thanks for the response. I'm trying to determine if the difference between two values is statistically significant or not. This is like calculating the difference between two or more levels when the predictor is a categorical variable. Except here I have a numerical predictor. Does this make sense? I'm just trying to see if prob1 and prob2 are statistically different. They cannot be compared because they are just one value. So I'm trying to create a normal distribution around them using the model's standard error. Then, I'm running a t-test between them.

Comment: Hi @ap920311, welcome to Cross Validated. What do you think "statistically significant" means in this context? Your model is specifying $\text{logit}(p) = \beta_0 + \beta_1\times\text{Input}$, so if you change the value of Input, then expected value of $p$ is going to change by definition.

Comment: Hello - thank you so much for your engagement with this. You're exactly right - the ``logit(p) `` will change with values of the Input. 

If I had a categorical variable as Input, I could have compared the statistical significance with ``Input = value 1`` as reference, and ``Input = value 2`` as another level of the Input.  But here, I need to know if, for two values of the Input (when it is numeric), can I find if ``logit(p1)`` and ``logit(p2)`` are significantly different.
Since ``logit(p1)`` and ``logit(p2)`` are single values, I tried to create a normal distribution around them.